# Set offset for a input type=hidden

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have an html element of `input type="hidden"`. I need to attach a datepicker to it, which gets trigerred on clicking a button.

The datepicker tries to lookup where to position itself, using the `$(attachedElement).offset()`, which is (0, 0) for a hidden element.

Is there a way to set the offset for a hidden input?

Comment: Why not just use `input type="date"`?

Comment: @Jonathan as I don't want the input to the visible. Hence the "which gets trigerred on clicking a button." part.

Comment: What datepicker do you use?

Comment: What does the type have to do with visibility?

Comment: @lvil: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in a project where we had to do the exact same thing. Even though our solution become a bit more complex then the following, the example describes more or less the approach we used!

We end up wrapping the input.hidden element with a className!

```
<form name="shabba-form">

  <input type="text" name="fullname" value="Shabba Ranks">

  <div class="hiddenField">
    <input type="hidden" name="myHiddenInput" value="foo">
  </div>

</form>
```

Now, you can select the wanted input element and then check the parent location in your document!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var data = $('input[name="myHiddenInput"]').parent('.hiddenField ').offset();

  console.log(data);

});
```

In case you prefer, you can see a live example here http://jsbin.com/pugux/1/

- Remember that the wrapper class can have any style, as long is not display:hidden, you can make it not visible using   visibility: hidden, height: 0px, opacity: 0 and stuff like that.

Hope this helps!